# Load file content from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm setting up my new API server, I did store **image** in my database, but how should I load it?

I Already tried libraries and method (responding the file content as an HTML, using **streamifier** library) but it wont work out for me.

Comment: Could you, please, add some more details and add some code snippets? How do you store your images (base64 encoded text, protobuf, something else)?

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem, by loading the **base64** as the `src` of the image. I worked out very well for me.